# Android Database connection, reading and writing data

Tags: php, android, mysql, database

I'm trying to build an android app, which "cooperates" with my website, so it should be able to read and manipulate the same data, which is accessible on my website.

But at the moment, I have no Idea how to do that. The database is a MySQL database, on the website I'm accessing it with PDO.

So the question now is: How can I read and write from the database by the Android App? How can I establish a database connection and what follows then?

I wasn't able to find something in the internet, working with that.

So is there a way to do this with php-files or how does this work?

*One more explanation, so you know what I mean: Think about a website, where you can just post some words about something, so let's say it's a plattform where users can talk about bananas. What I want now, is that if you enter a new comment about bananas on the website, it should appear on your app as well, as well the possibility to enter a new comment on your app, that appears on your website. So both (the website, and the app) should access the same MySQL database.*

FYI: I'm using Android Studio to develop the app, and testing it directly on my smartphone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going about this the wrong way. If you allow your android app to connect directly to the database, you'll have to embed your database credentials into the application, which someone *will* be able to get hold of and bypass all your security restrictions built into the app.

Consider writing an API on the website that the Android app talks to - you can then do all the security checks and sanity checking there where they can't be interfered with from the app.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to establish database connections.
You don't have to make android app to use the same data. You have to make android app to use the same site.

All you need is to make your android app send same HTTP requests that browser sends.
And to make your site send reply in JSON instead of HTML. If you were using templates, it would be piece of cake.